# What are the advantages of creating a Fragment vs Extending a View or ViewGroup?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

We recently converted an app from a multiple activity based one, to one with a single activity with multiple fragments. The activities that became Fragments used to contain fragments themselves, so we use child fragment managers to host the Fragments in the Fragments (these child fragments I should add, are small and there can be 4 or 5 these on the screen at one time).

This has caused a few issues, namely having to create, and keep track of Unique IDs for the Fragment holders. (Which cause headaches when dealing with the Backstack as well as if any are in any sort of AdapterViews).

We're thinking of just rewriting these components to extend some sort of ViewGroup, likely FrameLayout or LinearLayout. We already do that anyway in some cases, but I was wondering if there are **any disadvantages to doing it that way?** (I must admit, **I don't really see the big deal about Fragments... anything you can do with Fragments, you can do by creating a Custom View. Is this wrong?**).

Comment: Well, as far as them being a big deal, fragments don't have to have a view attached to it so it can be used as a background worker and can also be reused in many activities. I don't know if that means you're wrong, I imagine you're probably right, fragments *are* optional. I understand, as you have maybe just found out, that they are hell to add after the fact though.

Comment: @BobbyDigital - I've seen that explanation referenced a few times (re: optional for fragment to have a view, as they can be there for background operations), but how is that any better than a POJO, or a class that extends AsyncTask for instance if that's what's required?

Comment: You got me. I think it's actually the "standard" way of doing things. I'm learning android from a book that stresses using them always but basically says it's the pattern most used in "real life" and instead of stumbling over trying to add them later do it from the get go. So my activities, that extend a SingleFragmentActivity class do nothing but `return new MyFragment();`. ??

Comment: *I don't really see the big deal about Fragments... anything you can do with Fragments, you can do by creating a Custom View.* -the important thing with fragments is you're backed by the SDK. With just custom views you need to handle everything which, personally I would find more troublesome then using fragments and making those work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit of a reverse answer, explaining fragment use. In general you can do most things with Activities, but as the SDK supports fragments, many things will become more cumbersome (ViewPager is an example where fragment use is great).

**The advantages (of fragments):** code encapsulation, reusable chunks of UI.

**The disadvantages (of fragments):** more code (e.g. FragmentManager, FragmentTransaction).

Your original use of activities was good, it's not a case where I would have switched to fragments.

Let's say I designed a mobile phone app with two activities: ContactList and ContactDetails. So far so good, no reason to use fragments yet. If I wanted to support a larger device, it would behoove me to display both screens side by side. This is where fragments come in handy. In terms of exactly how to structure your activities/fragments, there's some good advice here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html#Fragments

Here are the important bits:

> ***Multiple fragments, one activity:***
>
> Use one activity regardless of the
> device size, but decide at runtime whether to combine fragments in the
> layout (to create a multiple-pane design) or swap fragments (to create
> a single-pane design).

Or...

> **Multiple fragments, multiple activities:**
>
> On a tablet, place multiple fragments in one activity; on a handset,
> use separate activities to host each fragment. For example, when the
> tablet design uses two fragments in an activity, use the same activity
> for handsets, but supply an alternative layout that includes just the
> first fragment. When running on a handset and you need to switch
> fragments (such as when the user selects an item), start another
> activity that hosts the second fragment.

.

> The approach you choose
> depends on your design and personal preferences. The first option (one
> activity; swapping fragments) requires that you determine the screen
> size at runtime and dynamically add each fragment as
> appropriate—rather than declare the fragments in your activity's XML
> layout—because you cannot remove a fragment from an activity if it's
> been declared in the XML layout. When using the first technique, you
> might also need to update the action bar each time the fragments
> change, depending on what actions or navigation modes are available
> for each fragment. In some cases, these factors might not affect your
> design, so using one activity and swapping fragments might work well
> (especially if your tablet design requires that you add fragments
> dynamically anyway). Other times, however, dynamically swapping
> fragments for your handset design can make your code more complicated,
> because you must manage all the fragment combinations in the
> activity's code (rather than use alternative layout resources to
> define fragment combinations) and manage the back stack of fragments
> yourself (rather than allow the normal activity stack to handle
> back-navigation).